# Core data saving but not saving - Dedicated queue jumping threads

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to run a syncing engine in the background, and am using a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` like so:

```
    - (NSManagedObjectContext *)workerContext
{

    NSManagedObjectContext* workerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    workerContext.parentContext = self.mainContext;
    return workerContext;
}
```

I figured I needed a dedicated background queue so I've created this as well:

```
- (dispatch_queue_t)syncQueue {
    if (!_syncQueue) {
        _syncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.me.syncEngineSyncQueue", 0);
    }
    return _syncQueue;
}
```

I'm running into a problem where an NSManagedObject deletion is happening, however, it gets reversed. My current guess is that it has something to do with threading.

I logged breakpoint in my sync engine and noticed that the same `syncQueue` runs on different threads at different times. Is this possibly my problem?

If so, how do I create a dispatch_queue that runs consistently on one thread?

Answer (score 0):

> I figured I needed a dedicated background queue so I've created this
>   as well:

Bzzzzt.  Wrong.  Core Data takes care of this for you.  When you initialized your MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, it came with its own internally managed GCD queue.  You don't bother with it at all.

However, any work related to that MOC **must** be done via the `performBlock` API for `NSManagedObjectContext`.  That API, among other things, basically places your block on the special private GCD queue, and schedules it for execution.

> If so, how do I create a dispatch_queue that runs consistently on one
>   thread?

You don't.  That's part of the beauty of GCD.  You insert blocks of code onto a message queue, and "some" thread peels them off an executes them.  You could care less exactly which thread is doing so (except for main queue stuff).

**EDIT**

> Gotcha. However, I still need to save the mainContext which is the
>   parent of my workerContext, right? Do I need to call that save in the
>   main thread? Right now I'm doing [self.mainContext save:&error]; in
>   the main thread after saving the workerContext using
>   performBlockAndWait –  Ramsel 5 hours ago

You are better off thinking about each context as an entity of its own, and only "take advantage" of knowing that the main context runs on the main thread when interacting with UI elements, which require interaction on the main thread.

If you want to save the parent context after saving the child, do something like this, which is a possible category method on `NSManagedObjectContext`.

```
- (void)_saveRecursively:(BOOL)recursiveSave
          withCompletion:(void(^)(NSError *error))completion {
    NSError *error;
    if ([self save:&error]) {
        error = nil;
        NSManagedObjectContext *parent = self.parentContext;
        if (parent != nil && recursiveSave) {
            return [parent performBlock:^{
                [parent _saveRecursively:recursiveSave withCompletion:completion];
            }];
        }
    }
    completion(error);
}
```

The above method is "private" and should no be exposed.  It saves the current context.  If asked to do a recursive save, it will keep saving up the hierarchy until it gets to the end, or until one of the save operations fails.

It will then invoke the completion handler, passing an instance of `NSError` if it failed or `nil` if it was successful.

```
- (void)saveRecursively:(BOOL)recursiveSave
         withCompletion:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *moc, NSError *error))completion {
    [self _saveRecursively:recursiveSave withCompletion:^(NSError *error) {
        if (completion) {
            [self performBlock:^{
                completion(self, error);
            }];
        }
    }];
}
```

This method provides a category API for users.  It ensures that the completion block is invoked asynchronously from within the protected confines of the originally saving context.  This way, you can guarantee that the completion block can be used safely without having to call another `performBlock`.

```
- (void)saveWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *moc, NSError *error))completion {
    [self saveRecursively:YES withCompletion:completion];
}
```

This provides a convenience method for saving the entire hierarchy asynchronously.

This means that you can call the save method like so...

```
[childContext saveWithCompletion:^(NSManagedObjectContext *moc, NSError *error) {
    // moc will be the same as childContext, and you can use the variable moc
    // safely, knowing this block is running in its own performBlock
    if (error) {
        // Handle the save error
    } else {
        // Handle the successful save
    }
}];
```

Comment: Gotcha. However, I still need to save the `mainContext` which is the parent of my `workerContext`, right? Do I need to call that save in the main thread? Right now I'm doing `[self.mainContext save:&error];` in the main thread after saving the `workerContext` using `performBlockAndWait`